# pyparsing command line strings with line continuations

Tags: python, pyparsing

I'm trying to use pyparsing to parse command line style strings in which the arguments themselves may contain backslash line continuations, such as the value for `-arg4` in the following example:

```
import pyparsing as pp

cmd = r"""shellcmd -arg1 val1 -arg2 val2 \
-arg3 val3 \
-arg4 'quoted \
    line-continued \
    string \
'"""

continuation = '\\' + pp.LineEnd()

option = pp.Word('-', pp.alphanums)
arg1 = ~pp.Literal('-') + pp.Word(pp.printables)
arg2 = pp.quotedString
arg2.ignore(continuation)
arg = arg1 | arg2

command = pp.Word(pp.alphas) + pp.ZeroOrMore(pp.Group(option + pp.Optional(arg)))
command.ignore(continuation)

print command.parseString(cmd)
```

The result is:

```
['shellcmd', ['-arg1', 'val1'], ['-arg2', 'val2'], ['-arg3', 'val3'], ['-arg4', "'quoted"]]
```

when what I want is something like this:

```
['shellcmd', ['-arg1', 'val1'], ['-arg2', 'val2'], ['-arg3', 'val3'], ['-arg4', 'quoted line-continued string']]
```

I would very much appreciate your help in pointing out my error and the fix.

Answer (score 6):

Using `cmd` as you've posted it above, I would parse it like this:

```
from pyparsing import *

continuation = ('\\' + LineEnd()).suppress()
name = Word(alphanums)

# Parse out the multiline quoted string
def QString(s,loc,tokens):
    text = Word(alphanums+'-') + Optional(continuation)
    g    = Combine(ZeroOrMore(text),adjacent=False, joinString=" ")
    return g.parseString(tokens[0])

arg    = name + Optional(continuation)
qarg   = QuotedString("\'",multiline=True)
qarg.setParseAction(QString)

vals   = Group(ZeroOrMore(arg | qarg))
option = Literal("-").suppress() + Group(name + vals)
grammar = name + ZeroOrMore(option)

sol = grammar.parseString(cmd)
print sol
```

Giving:

```
['shellcmd', ['arg1', ['val1']], ['arg2', ['val2']], ['arg3', ['val3']], ['arg4', ['quoted line-continued string']]]
```

The real key here is using the `QuotedString` option `multiline=True` which saves a lot of headache. This solution is a bit more flexible than the one you proposed, being able to handle multiple arguments i.e. `-arg a b c` or even `-arg a b 'long-string-with-dashes' c d e`.

Comment: @KeithWald I'm glad that helped and welcome to Stack Overflow! If your solution is solved, please "accept" the answer by clicking on the checkmark.